# How can I identify what is causing UI lag caused slow "layout effects" in React Dev Tools Profiler?

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

While working in React, I'm noticing a specific UI action causes the app to freeze entirely, so I decided to profile it using the React Dev Tools Profiler.

Interestingly, there is a specific render that has massive 2145 millisecond duration for something called "Layout Effects". This coincides with the freezing I'm seeing.

[image: DevTools Screenshot One]

I tried looking into *what* exactly is causing this, but when hovering over specific yellow / blocks I never get any numbers for "layout effects" to tell me which component could be causing this. I only get a single number for what I assume is the render. For example:

[image: DevTools Screenshot Two]

Is there any way I could quickly find what could be causing these long layout effects using either the React or Chrome Devtools?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can figure out which component is causing the slow performance is by commenting some of the components and rending the app to see if the performance improves . I found that approach to be easier than the React Profiler.